# How to read csv file and convert one column to Map[String, String] type in Scala+Spark?

Tags: dataframe, scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `.csv` file with several columns.

One row as an example:

```
aaa,bbb,{'foo': 'xxx', 'bar': 'zzz'}
```

I want to read it and transform to the following typed schema:

```
field1: String,
field2: String,
field3: Map[String, String]
```

I can do this with primitive types like this:

```
private val someSchema =
    StructType(
      StructField("field1", StringType, true) ::
      StructField("field2", StringType, true) ::
      StructField("field3", StringType, true) :: Nil)

     spark.read
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", true)
      .schema(someSchema)
      .load("path.csv")
```

But when it comes to Map[String, String] it does not work due to

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: CSV
> data source does not support map<string,string> data type.

How can I do this another way?

Comment: Perhaps you can read it as `String` and then apply `from_json()` to it. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#from_json(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,schema:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,options:java.util.Map[String,String]):org.apache.spark.sql.Column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read it as string then convert it to MapType using `from_json` function to parse it as `map<string,string>`:

```
val result = df.withColumn(
  "field3",
  from_json(col("field3"), lit("map<string,string>"))
)
```

---

However, from your example it seems the values are not escaped in the file, spark will fail parsing it because you have commas (delimiter) inside the values of column `field3`.

In this case you can read the file as text, then replace the commas inside the `{}` by another delimiter say `;`,  split by `,` to get the 3 columns and convert the column `field3` to map using [`str_to_map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#str_to_map) function:

```
val df = spark.text("/path/file.csv")

val result = df.withColumn(
    "value",
    split(regexp_replace(col("value"), ",(?=[^{}]*\\})", ";"), ",")
).select(
    col("value")(0).as("field1"),
    col("value")(1).as("field2"),
    regexp_replace(col("value")(2), "[{}' ]", "").as("field3")
).withColumn(
    "field3",
    expr("str_to_map(field3, ';', ':')")
)

result.show
//+------+------+------------------------+
//|field1|field2|field3                  |
//+------+------+------------------------+
//|aaa   |bbb   |[foo -> xxx, bar -> zzz]|
//+------+------+------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you! First option worked just fine